# O que é capped collection?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql, collection

Olá, gostaria de saber o que é Coleção limitada (Capped Collection) e para que usamos em MongoDB.

Comment: Veja [Documentação Mongo/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). Pelo que entedi,a grosso modo são coleções de tamanho fixo com objectivo de conseguir um boa performance. Sendo de memória circular, quando cheias apagam o último elemento automaticamente e inserem elementos conforme a ordem de inserção.

Comment: Ok, obrigada :D